# How do you break on a specific line of a require'd file in the Perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I've got a Perl script, let's call it `A.pl` where the first two lines look something like this:

```
 require 'B.pl';
 require 'C.pl';
```

Where both `B.pl` and `C.pl` each have their own cavalcade of requires. I need to set a breakpoint on a specific line of `C.pl`. In GDB I'd do something like:

```
b C.pl:830
```

However that doesn't seem to work at all here.  Is it possible? Am I close?

Comment: I was never able to figure this out. Going to accept the upvoted answer just so this question isn't left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in one step, but you can change to the file you want and then set a breakpoint on a specific line:

```
DB<1> f C.pl
1    #!perl -w
2    # This is C.pl
3    # ...

DB<2> b 830

DB<3> c
```

Comment: `f` doesn't appear to work with `require` says the file isn't loaded.

Comment: You have to load a file before you can set a breakpoint inside it, although you can do `b load <file>` to break on loading a file.

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't ever break at all.

Answer (score 3):

You could also edit C.pl adding this:

```
$DB::single = 1;
```

and the debugger will stop immediately after executing that line, and before executing the next line. This is similar to Ruby's 'debugger' statement.

See also: [perldoc DB](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB.html)

Comment: This should be $DB::single = 1;
The single colon there is incorrect syntax for addressing this variable.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the cheap trick of the debugger's 'R' (restart) command. Here's a sample program:

```
#/usr/bin/perl -d
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();
```

and let's assume that we want to break at LWP::UserAgent's new() method. Do this:

```
bash$ perl -d sample.pl --whatever-arguments
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(use_mech.pl:7):  my $foo = WWW::Mechanize::Pluggable->new();
```

Load the module you want to set the breakpoint in:

```
  DB<1> use LWP::UserAgent
```

Print its @INC entry to figure out what file you just loaded (needed to do the 'f' command):

```
  DB<2> p $INC{"LWP/UserAgent.pm"}
/Users/joemcmahon/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm
```

Switch to that file with 'f':

```
  DB<3> f /Users/joemcmahon/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm
1   package LWP::UserAgent;
2   
3:  use strict;
4:  use vars qw(@ISA $VERSION);
5   
6:  require LWP::MemberMixin;
7:  @ISA = qw(LWP::MemberMixin);
8:  $VERSION = "6.04";
9   
10: use HTTP::Request ();
```

We want to break in new(), so find it:

```
  DB<4> /new
20: sub new
```

Find the first executable statement in the sub via 'l':

```
  DB<5> l
20  sub new
21  {
22      # Check for common user mistake
23:     Carp::croak("Options to LWP::UserAgent should be key/value pairs, not hash reference") 
24          if ref($_[1]) eq 'HASH'; 
25  
26:     my($class, %cnf) = @_;
27  
28:     my $agent = delete $cnf{agent};
29:     my $from  = delete $cnf{from};
```

Set a breakpoint at this line:

```
  DB<5> b 23
```

*Restart* the debugger:

```
  DB<6> R
Warning: some settings and command-line options may be lost!

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(use_mech.pl:7):  my $foo = WWW::Mechanize::Pluggable->new();
```

Run the program, and you break at the point you wanted.

```
  DB<6> c
LWP::UserAgent::new(/Users/joemcmahon/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:23):
23:     Carp::croak("Options to LWP::UserAgent should be key/value pairs, not hash reference") 
24:         if ref($_[1]) eq 'HASH'; 
  DB<6>
```

This technique is particularly handy for debugging import() problems; you can load the module that's having trouble. set a breakpoint in import(), and then restart. The debugger will stop in import() for the module you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `c` command to skip past the `require`s and then setting a breakpoint. For example

```
main::(prog:6):    require "A.pl";
  DB<1> l 
6==>    require "A.pl";
7   
8:  bar();
  DB<2> c 8
main::(prog:8): bar();
  DB<3> b bar
  DB<4> c
main::bar(C.pl:2):    print "A\n";
  DB<4>
```

Comment: After I step into the second file then try to set a breakpoint on the line it tells me that that line is not breakable.

Comment: @Morinar: You can only set breakpoints on lines that are executable. For multi-line statements that usually means the first line of the expression.

Comment: The line I'm trying to set a breakpoint is a single line `if` statement. I can't seem to set a breakpoint on ANY line of that file. Something is wrong here, but I can't seem to figure out what.